# having clause in mysql query error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to the fetch nearest location according lat and lng but I want to add **having distance < 5** clause in query.

But where I can use.??

```
select p.id, p.name, p_i.image as image, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(26.916279) ) * 
cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
cos( radians( lng ) - radians(75.8082) ) + 
sin( radians(26.916279) ) * 
sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
from `places` as p 
inner join `place_images` as p_i 
on p.`id` = p_i.`place_id` 
where p.`city_id` = '1' 
and p.status = 'active' 
and p_i.display_order = '1' 
limit 0, 5
```

**current result**

[image]

Comment: The irony Tim is that `having` works and `where` doesn't :)  Well, maybe not irony, cuz we know `where` won't work, and we are conditioned to thinking `having` only works with a `group by`

Comment: I see the error of my ways.  The reason is that MySQL cannot guarantee that the alias column will be computed at the time the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.  Using `HAVING` is a way around this.  Actually, the alternative is to just reuse the Haversine formula in the `WHERE` clause but this is ugly.

Comment: yeah, that was never on the table, with that performance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `having` clause at last, just before `limit`

```
select p.id, p.name, p_i.image as image, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(26.916279) )
 * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(75.8082) )
 + sin( radians(26.916279) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
 from `places` as p inner join `place_images` as p_i on p.`id` = p_i.`place_id`
 where p.`city_id` = '1' and p.status = 'active' and p_i.display_order = '1' 
 HAVING distance < 5 limit 0, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
where p.`city_id` = '1' and p.status = 'active' 
and p_i.display_order = '1' 
HAVING distance < 5
limit 0, 5
```

use `limit` at last

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.id, p.name, p_i.image as image, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(26.916279) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(75.8082) ) + sin( radians(26.916279) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance from `places` as p inner join `place_images` as p_i on p.`id` = p_i.`place_id` 
where p.`city_id` = '1' 
and p.status = 'active' 
and p_i.display_order = '1' 
HAVING distance < 5 # add this
limit 0, 5
```